UV editor all purple (Solid mode viewport is set to texture not color)
I have the situation as in the title. My queston was closed before suggesting that my viewport might be set to color in solid mode. It isn't. But What I did notice is that no matter what object I select, in the UV editor I see the same texture name with a solid purple color. I've changed around the texture of teh selected part, and I still only see this option selected (at around top left/middle of the screenshot). Thanks if you have any suggestions.

Do not ask questions twice! And I've already told you what is going on there in the comments the last time you asked this.

I don't know what to do based on that.

Still no need to ask the question again. And there is nothing wrong in your scene, you just have to select a different texture in the material if you want to see it in this Solid mode. If you do not understand what I explain in my linked answer there which explains in detail what the different options are and how Blender decides which texture to show, there is nothing more I can tell you. If you can't make it work in this shading mode, switch to Material Preview or Rendered. If you don't know how to even do that, please try to learn the basics of using the 3D Viewport.

...and for the UV Editor on the left: the screenshot shows you have opened the dropdown menu where you can choose an image to be displayed. If you don't want to see the normal map, why don't you just simply select a different image - preferably one without the suffix "normal" if you don't want to see a purple image?
